# sencha touch run animation before destroy view

Tags: extjs, viewport, destroy

To make 'back button', I tried destroy view because in my app, I make several views with the same view file changing store.

Here is my controller code,

```
onTapBackBtn:function(view) {
    view.parent.parent.destroy().runAnimation({type: 'slide',direction: 'left'});
}
```

It can destroy view, but I cannot see any animation with this code at all :(

There is no way to implemente animation with destroy() method?

If there is any better alternative way, Please let me know :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an animation after a component is destroyed. Run the animation first, and use after animation callbacks or add a listener to hide event. Once the animation is complete or the component is completed hiding, then destroy it.